# VAG TP 2.0 complete list of AT commands

Tags: vw, obd-ii, dtc, can-bus, elm-327

I am trying to find DTCs from various ECUs in a Skoda Rapid 2009 model.
I am using OBDLink SX (elm 327 chip) and Putty (similar to HyperTerminal)

https://jazdw.net/tp20
This link gives the list of commands that I should request the ECUs of any VAG car because they run on TP 2.0 protocol. But I am unable to get any response. It always gives me 'NO DATA'. I think I am missing 'AT' commands like maybe set timeout or wakeup message.

```
>at z 
at z 


ELM327 v2.1 



>at h1 
at h1 
OK 

>at l1 
at l1 
OK 

>at s1 
at s1 
OK 

>at pb c001 
at pb c001 
OK 

>at d1 
at d1 
OK 

>at sp b 
at sp b 
OK 

>at sh 200 
at sh 200 
OK 

>05 c0 00 10 00 03 01 1 
05 c0 00 10 00 03 01 1 
205 7 00 D0 00 03 68 07 01 

>03 c0 00 10 00 03 01 1 
03 c0 00 10 00 03 01 1 
203 7 00 D0 00 03 90 07 01 


>at sh 768 
at sh 768 
OK 

>at cra 300 
at cra 300 
OK 

>a0 0f 8a ff 32 ff 
a0 0f 8a ff 32 ff 
NO DATA 

>a0 0f 8a ff 32 ff 1 
a0 0f 8a ff 32 ff 1 
NO DATA
```

Can someone help me to list the step by step commands to get VAG DTCs from engine, ABS, Airbag, EPS etc. Online resources will be helpful too.

Comment: Sounds like a computer science question to. Have you tried that forum?

Comment: It's not a CS question. A lot of automobile enthusiasts work on studying CAN bus data @DanZ

Answer (score -3):

I hope you have solution your question!
But I see mistake in your command

203 7 00 D0 00 03 90 07 01

Response from 790 address of unit! but you set at sh 768 it is mistake!!!